# Update JSlider position used as SeekBar

Tags: java, swing, media-player, jslider

I'm developing a music player using Java + Swing. I use the BasicPlayer 3.0 library to play the files.

I'm using a SeekTask to update the SliderBar position according to the EncodedStreamPosition, together with a Timer to schedule the task every 30ms to update the knob position.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;

import entities.BasicPlayer;
import javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayerException;

public class MiniPlayer {

    private JSlider seekbar;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private Timer timer;
    private SeekTask seekTask;

    private BasicPlayer player;

    public MiniPlayer() throws BasicPlayerException {

        String path = "path\to\file.mp3";
        File song = new File(path);
        player = new BasicPlayer();
        player.open(song);

        frame = new JFrame("Media Player");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 200));

        panel = new JPanel();
        seekbar = new JSlider(0,1000, 0);

        seekbar.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
                timer.cancel();
                timer.purge();
                seekTask.cancel();

                JSlider slider = (JSlider) event.getSource();
                int position = slider.getValue();
                slider.setValue(position);
                position = slider.getValue();
                int total = player.getEncodedLength();
                int newposition = (int) (total * ((double) position / 1000)); 
                try {
                    player.seek(newposition);
                    timer = new Timer();
                    seekTask = new SeekTask();
                    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(seekTask, 30, 30);

                } catch (BasicPlayerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                slider.setValue(position);
            }

        });
        panel.add(seekbar);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        playSong();
    }

    public void playSong() {
        timer = new Timer();
        seekTask = new SeekTask();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(seekTask, 30, 30);
        try {
            player.play();
        } catch (BasicPlayerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class SeekTask extends TimerTask{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int bytesread = player.getEncodedStreamPosition();
            int encodedLength = player.getEncodedLength();
            double currentval = ((double)(bytesread) / encodedLength) * 1000;

            seekbar.setValue((int)currentval);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new MiniPlayer();
                } catch (BasicPlayerException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I created a simplified test to reproduce the issue. I modified the BasicPlayer class to access the encodedLength and position.

Edit 1: When I release the knob the player continues playing from where it was prior to the click. How to update the player so it starts playing from the new position? I'm using the method seek to move the new encoded stream position.

Comment: I was following the new question template and thought the question was there. Hopefully, it's clear now.

Comment: *" How to update the player so it starts playing from the new position?"* I had more success when using a `JProgressBar` for seeking in a track. Add a `MouseListener` to discover when it changes (by the user clicking on it). Not sure if that's the problem here, but I wouldn't try debugging one based on a `JSlider`.